# 16.04 Very slow starting boot due to wifi

Tags: boot, networking, lenovo, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 16.04 xenial on a Lenovo X1 Carbon 4th gen.
I' m having a hard time finding a solution for this:

```
[   10.293464] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   10.295070] audit: type=1400 audit(1470676585.029:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=2381 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.295079] audit: type=1400 audit(1470676585.029:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=2381 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.295084] audit: type=1400 audit(1470676585.029:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//pxgsettings" pid=2381 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.295089] audit: type=1400 audit(1470676585.029:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//sanitized_helper" pid=2381 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   10.327830] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   10.327833] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   10.327835] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   10.327837] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   10.327839] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   10.327841] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   10.327843] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   10.327845] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   10.327847] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   10.327849] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   10.327851] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[  100.029697] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[  100.235347] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
```

I ran a [full wireless check](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22713154/) with the Ubuntu Forums wireless-info script, but I don't know what to think about it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try entirely turning your internet off, and booting your system up. You don't need wifi to boot a system up.